# What is the point of checking the transactions queue if we can just check the receipts?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

For Apple in app purchase, it seems we are supposed to observe the transactions queue:

```
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)  {
  switch (transaction.transactionState) {
      case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
      ...
}
```

but we also need to validate the receipt (parsing the content at `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];`). But then... can we just take the shortcut to look at the receipt directly? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate the receipt you should [create custom server](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) and  send the receipt to the server. Also receipt contains all transactions and you should find last transaction in it, it is not very easy way to show to a user some message about purchasing.
I use transactions for statistics and for quick information and the receipt for validation of purchasing.
Also you can use receipt for double check of purchasing, if the receipt is not contain appropriate transaction, you can restrict access to the content.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know in the case of auto renewable transactions (say monthly) if the receipt contains 1 transaction total or 1 per month?

Comment: I have auto renewable subscription in my application, and the receipt contains different transactions for different periods (any renewal is a purchasing). If you need to  determine active period, you should check all transactions and calculate the period: https://apple.co/2I39Y29

Comment: thanks! it was very hard to find the information, tons of doc just for this... crazy